Probability distribution of a number of $m$ combinations from a set $S$ in a combination of length $l \le |S|$
Given a set of $N$ different numbers. I am interested in the probability $P(m,k,l,N)$ that a number of $m$ combinations (without repetition) of this set, each of length $k$, is not contained in a random combination of length $l$ with $k \le l \le N$.
For $m=1$ obviously applies
$$
1-P(m=1,k,l,N) = \binom{l}{k} \Big{/} \binom{N}{k} = \binom{N-k}{l-k} \Big{/} \binom{N}{l} .
$$
And for $k=l$ we get
$$
1-P(m,k,l = k,N) = m \Big{/} \binom{N}{k} .
$$
For $m>1$ and $k < l$, however, the probability depends on the specific choice of the $m$ combinations! Is it possible to specify a probability distribution for $1 < m  \le \binom{N}{k}$, in particular for $1 \ll k \le l \le N$?
We can assume that we know the distribution of the elements in the combinations of size $k$. For random $m$ combinations, the probability for each of the $N$ numbers is $k/N$. As an example, let us assume a distribution in which one part of the numbers is distributed with $p_1 \gt k/N$ and the other part with $p_2 \ll k/N$.

I'm not certain I understand this correctly. If for example the $N=4$ numbers are ${0,1,2,3}$ and the forbidden is ${0,1,2}$ (so $m=1, k=3$) and $l=3$, then are the good combinations
{0, 1, 3} {0, 2, 3} {1, 2, 3}
?

Yes, you have a total of $(N;l) = 4$ possible combinations of length $ l=k = 3$, one of which is not allowed, i.e. the probability is $1 - 1/(N; l) = 3/4$. I had incorrectly stated the complementary probability in the question and have corrected this.

Here's a way to calculate $P$ for a specific set $\mathcal B = \{B_1, B_2, \dots, B_m\}$ of forbidden combinations (well, they are subsets of $[N]$ of size $k$).
It's inclusion-exclusion with the sets of those combinations that do contain $B_j$ for $j=1,\dots, m$. But we can calculate the result iteratively one $B_j$ at a time.
Call $X = \{S \subset [N] : |S|=l\}$. The I-E sets are $A_j = \{S \in X : B_j \subset S\}$.
Let
$$
q(x; t_1, t_2, \dots, t_N) = \sum_{J \subset \mathcal{P}(\mathcal B)}x^{|J|}\prod_{u=1}^N t_u^{U(J, u)}
$$
where $U(J, u)$ is the indicator of $u \in \bigcup_{j\in J} B_j$. Then we have
$$
P = \frac{1}{\binom{N}{l}}{\large\sum_{cx^rt^\alpha \text{ term of } q} } c(-1)^r \binom{N-|\alpha|_1}{l-|\alpha|_1}
$$
because the size of an intersection of $A_j$'s, when the size of the union of the corresponding $B_j$'s is $|\alpha|$, is $\binom{N-|\alpha|_1}{l-|\alpha|_1}$. This is because $|\alpha|_1$ elements are fixed to be in the combination so we just choose the remaining ones.
As said, we can calculate $q$ iteratively. Note also that we can restrict $|\alpha|_1 \leq l$.
Code $B_j$ as its indicator vector $(b_{j1}, b_{j2}, \dots, b_{jN})$.
Let $q_0 = 1$ and
$${\large
q_j = q_{j-1} + x  \sum_{cx^rt^\alpha \text{ term of } q_{j-1}} cx^r \prod_{u=1}^N t_u^{\max (b_{j,u}+\alpha_u, 1)} 
}
$$
and we can drop terms whose total degree in $t$ becomes larger than $l$.
Explanation: we either don't take $B_j$ (and $q_{j-1}$ stays as is) or we take $B_j$ (and $r$ goes up by one and the union size updates accordingly). So $q = q_m$.
Here's the algorithm as Python code:
from collections import defaultdict
from math import comb as binomial

def countGood(bs, l, N):
    q = defaultdict(int)
    q[(0,)*N] = 1
    for b in bs:
        bT = tuple(1 if j in b else 0 for j in range(N))
        q2 = defaultdict(int)
        for t in q:
            q2[t] += q[t]
            t2 = tuple(1 if bT[j] or t[j] else 0 for j in range(N))
            if sum(t2)<=l: q2[t2] += -1 * q[t]
        q = q2
    return sum(q[t]*binomial(N-sum(t), l-sum(t)) for t in q)
    

testN = 20
testL = 10
testBs = [(0,1,2), (1,2,3), (3,4,5), (2,5,6), (2,8,13)]
testM = len(testBs)
testK = len(testBs[0])
ans = countGood(testBs, testL, testN)
print (ans)

Since the loop in run $m$ times and the size of $q$ is limited by $2^m$ and $\binom{N}{l} \leq 2^N$, it is $\mathcal{O} (m2^{\min(m, N)})$ time algorithm.

@siserman Thanks, I fixed those typos. I assume we are given the set of forbidden combinations $\mathcal B$ and then count the good combinations for it. But since you only mentioned the number $m$, do we also take this forbidden set as random too?

Only trained in theoretical physics, it took me a while to understand the answer almost completely. I still have a question, what is meant by $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{B})$. And there is probably a typo $q=q_m$ and the probability does not seem to be normalized?
However, the exact calculation of a probability for small $m,N$ using iterative I-E does not help me, since $N=O(n^2)$, $k,l= O(n)$ and $m = O(n^n)$ with $n \gg 1$. I am therefore rather looking for asymptotic statements depending on the structure (overlap) of the combinations. But maybe it is a good starting point for further analysis.

The point is that the $m = O(n^n)$ combinations result from some other calculations. These combinations are not random and have a large overlap, so the probability of having none of these combinations in a combination of size $l$ is much larger than if we had random combinations. And I would like to determine this probability approximately, e.g. as a function of a mean overlap.

I have added a further assumption about the distribution of the $m$ combinations in the question.
